# Reinitializing a real variable using Boolean If in Z3 Python API

Tags: python, z3

I need to reinitialized a real variable based on some some Boolean flag as follows.
Alongside changing the truth value of `location_next` I want to reinitialize `x_next` with another value. How can I do that?

```
location, location_next = Bools('location location_next')
x, x_next = Reals('x x_next')
...
location_next == If(And(Not(location), x_next >= 12),
                    True,
                    If(And(location, x_next <= 0), False, location))
```

Comment: @Maulwurn:  For those who are wondering,  [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/) is theorem prover by Microsoft research for which there exists a [Python binding](http://www4.in.tum.de/~boehmes/z3-python.html).

Comment: Z3 comes with its own Python bindings. Here is an online tutorial describing the Z3 Python API: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide

Comment: hi leo,thanx for your help yesterday. In continuation of our yesterday conversation, i have to make an addition. I need to update the location as well as reinitialize value of x_next based on the same condition. Since If is boolean , how to augment a real arithmetic constraint there??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `If` (in the Z3 API) can be also used to create non-Boolean expressions. 
We must have that for every `If(c, t1, t2)`, `c` has sort Boolean, and `t1` and `t2` have the same sort (type) `S`. In this case, `If(c, t1, t2)` is will produce a Z3 expression of sort `S`. Here is a small example:

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
print If(x > 0, x + 1, y - 1)
```

Here is a link with the example above: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/V4e

In the following example, we have a formula such that `x_next` is equal to `x+1` when `location` is `False` and `x >= 12`, is equal to `x-1` when `location` is `True` and `x <= 0`, and is equal to `x` otherwise.

```
x_next == If(And(Not(location), x >= 12),
             x+1,
             If(And(location, x <= 0), x-1, x))
```